# Issue with simple regex javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
String = "Part # 12345 MSRP $16.55
```

I simply want to be able to grab the numbers "12345" so I made it between # and M. the regular expression i came up with is....

```
....text().match(/#(.*)M/)
```

Comment: And, you're exact question is what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no digit before the part you want to extract, you can use following

```
var num = String.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array or `null`. You can use

```
string.match(/#\s*(\d+)\s*M/)[1]
```

If needed, add a test :

```
var m = string.match(/#\s*(\d+)\s*M/);
if (m) {
     var num = +m[1]; // the first captured group is at index 1
     console.log('number : ', num);
} else {
     console.log('no number')
}
```